# Build a simple lambda with dynamic expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm trying to understand how dynamic expressions work. So for learning purposes I'd like to do the following:

I have an object which I can currently access with a Linq statement that uses a lambda expression:

```
someObj.IncludeStory(x => x.News);
```

What I'd like to do is replace the labmda `x => x.News`with a string, for example:

```
string myLambda = "x => x.News";
someObj.IncludeStory(myLambda);
```

Obviously you can't do it like that, but as far as I understand you can achieve somewhat the same with Dynamic Expressions(?).

I've been looking at the [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) source code to get an idea of how this should work. But that only confuses me more. I think that library is far to complex for what I want. I don't need sorting, grouping and all that fancy stuff.

Basically my questions are:

1. Can I use Dynamic Expressions to generate a lambda like this dynamicaly: `x => x.News`?
2. If so, then how would I do this with a Dynamic Expression?

I find it hard to get started with this.

---

### What I've tried is something like:

```
        var expression = @"IncludeStory(x => x.News)";
        var p = Expression.Parameter(someObj.GetType(), "News");
        var e = myAlias.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expression);
        var result1 = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(someObj);
```

Comment: If you think [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) is confusing wait until you try parsing your own expressions. I'd persevere with Dynamic LINQ if I were you - it'll be a lot easier than trying to roll you own.

Comment: I don't know about Dynamic Expressions, but I think you can use a `delegate` here to achieve the same affect. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Enigmativity With Dynamic LINQ I can easily do what I want in a `Where()`, `Select()` etc. But I have a custom method called `IncludeStory`. Can I use Dynamic LINQ for that as well?

Comment: Btw, what is "Dynamic Expressions"?

Comment: @Vivendi - Good question. I don't know. Try the docs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DynamicExpression.ParseLambda to convert a string into an Expression Tree. For more detail go and see the project that comes with VS2010 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Samples\1033 -> CSharpSamples -> LinqSamples -> DynamicQuery (Also I think is part of the installation of higher versions)

Comment: I only have VS 2015 Community Edition, that comes without samples :-<